# numbering variables, when valid path is found

Tags: windows, batch-file

Maybe I did not give it a good title, anyway

Hi,

I writing some script in batch, and need help.

with `FOR` i checking all possible drives letters A-Z and when on some of that will be found `X:\Users\Public\Desktop` , then save this letter to numbered variable `1_windrive`, `2_windrive`, `3_windrive` etc........

but my code does not work, and i do not know where is problem.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set number=1
if not defined !number!_windrive (
for %%p in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist %%p:\Users\Public\Desktop (
set !number!_windrive=%%p
echo !number!%_windrive%
set /a "number=%number%+1"
)
pause
```

solution code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set number=1
if not defined windrive_!number! (
for %%p in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist %%p:\Users\Public\Desktop (
set windrive_!number!=%%p
CALL echo %%windrive_!number!%%
set /a number=number+1
)
)
echo %windir%
echo %windrive_1%
echo %windrive_2%
echo %windrive_3%
echo %windrive_4%
echo %windrive_5%
pause
```

Comment: You are not using delayed expansion here: `set /a "number=%number%+1"`.  But you can just write it like this: `set /a number+=1`

Comment: Also, naming a variable that start with a number may cause undesirable results.  As the cmd interpreter would not be able to differentiate between %1 and %1_windrive%.

Comment: Hmm, it is possible, but script crash when goes to command //                       if not defined !number!_windrive (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set windrive_!number!=%%p
CALL echo %%windrive_!number!%%
set /a number=number+1
```

The easy way to list the `windrive` variables set is

```
set windrive
```

As squishy says, starting a variable with a numeric is likely to cause `cmd` syntactic apoplexy.

`%var%` means "the value of `var` when the code-block was started" so it will remain unchanged as the loop progresses. `!var!` means the value as it changes within the loop.

quotes are not required for a `set/a`, neither is `%` nor `!` - the variable-name itself means "the run-time value of the variable" (ie as it changes within the loop) and this is regardless of whether or not `enabledelayedexpansion` has been invoked.

[edit - fixed `echo` within `for` loop]

Comment: apoplexy!  Learned a new word today!

Comment: okay, i reworked the code, as you can see up, but it still crashes at command // if not defined !number!_windrive ( //

Comment: 1. I've fixed the `echo` code in the `for` loop. The `call` adds an extra level of parsing. 2. Your code has unbalanced parentheses. Both the `for do` and `if not defined` need to be closed (one extra `)` will suffice.)

Comment: oh, yes, you are right, i forgot one ) at the end of the cycle. thanks!

Comment: okay it is looks good, it looks working. Thank you for your help to me!